# ¿Cómo vuelvo a habilitar la barra de menus y toolbar de Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, menu, toolbar

Estaba manipulando las opciones de vistas y desactivé la barra de menús y toolbar. Ya intenté con ALT+inicio y no funcionó. Gracias por la ayuda.

[image: muestra de android studio]

Comment: Qué es lo que desapareció, ¿la barra que tiene un montón de botones con imágenes o el típico menú de File, View, Edit, Navigate, Code y así?

Comment: " el típico menú de File, View, Edit, Navigate, Code y así? "

Comment: Ese menú se puede mostrar presionando Alt en la mayoría de programas

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo solucioné.
Ctrl + Alt + S
Aparece una ventana "Settings"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Si ocultas el menú principal, aún podrás acceder a él con la acción correspondiente: pulsar Ctrl+Shift+Ay buscar menú principal. Consulta justo en la documentacion:

[jetbrains.com](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2022.3/customize-actions-menus-and-toolbars.html#configure_quick_lists)